# UITableViewCell with CAShapeLayer bug with appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view cell with custom backgroundView. This background view have an overriden method:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}
```

In code I specify the path, stroke color, fill color and line width for layer of background view of my cells. Next I try to insert section into table view using method:

```
- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections 
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

And at this point I get a bug: layers of inserted cells are displayed only after animation of inserting. That is, during the animation cells have no background and border.

UPDATE:
This is how I set custom background for my cells:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = /* initializing cell */
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
frame.origin = CGPointZero;
cell.backgroundView = [[MYCellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
CAShapeLayer* shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)cell.backgroundView.layer;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
/* building path with some arcs and lines  */

shapeLayer.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
shapeLayer.fillColor = FILL_COLOR.CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = BORDER_COLOR.CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = LINE_WIDTH;
```

And I forgot to specify that I use CAShapeLayer only for customizing view of cells, not for animation.

Comment: Where are you placed CAShapeLayer animation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to specify that I use CAShapeLayer only for customizing view of cells, not for animation.